# Knockout js and ajax get method to display search results on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am converting an exisiting modal that contained search results into a search results page. (That being said the model shouldn't change.) The issue is I am having trouble with passing the search query string to the next page to display the results to a table from the query. I am confused as to where the get() call should be made to retrieve the data for the table.

```
<input id="searchInput" type="text" class="typeahead" placeholder="Search"      data-bind="value: searchQuery, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">

<a href="@Url.Action("SearchResults", "Admin")" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-bind="click: search">Search Results</a>
```

That's how I setup my search text box and my click binding for the search action.

```
function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.reviews = ko.observableArray();
        self.searchQuery = ko.observable();
        self.selectedReview = ko.observable();
        self.loadingPage = ko.observable(true);

        self.selectReview = function (review) {
            self.selectedReview(review);
        }
        self.viewReview = function (review) {
            document.location = '@Url.Content("~/Admin/Review?")' + review.id;
        }
        self.deleteReview = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/api/reviews/")' + self.selectedReview().id,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function () {
                    self.reviews.remove(self.selectedReview());
                    self.selectedReview(undefined);
                    $('#deleteReviewModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#reviewsTable').trigger('update');
                }
            });  
        }

        self.search = function() {
            //where I'm lost
        }
```

Do I put the GET call within that function, or do I put that in a script on the page to be rendered too?

Comment: Are you leaving the page you're on and going to a different URL?

Comment: Yes I am. Do you suggest passing the search query through URL parameters?

Comment: Yes. Once you leave the current page, your ViewModel is gone. No point in doing the work and then having to pass the results, unless you think the results would be smaller than the query info.

Comment: I agree. That was my first thought. Once I get to the other URL address how do I then use that parameter as the search string.

Comment: You'll pull it from window.location.search
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

Comment: Alright thanks. Lastly, is there an easier way to append the query string directly with javascript rather than use a Web API controller with an AJAX call?

Comment: Maybe http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/ ?